# Replace spacebar symbol with random word in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've been stuck with this code for MS Word.
My task is to change every spacebar in document with a random word from array.

I mean to put random word in document between every avaliable words. When I run my macros, it start to insert all words from array without any stop, so I must close Word to end cycle.

In example I use 5 words only, so my Rnd is from 1 to 4.

```
Sub TestRND()
    
    Const d = " "
    Dim x As Variant
    Randomize
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    x = Array(" Word1 ", " Word2 ", " Word3 ", " Word4 ", " Word5 ")
    With Selection
        .Find.Text = d
        .Find.MatchCase = True
        .Find.Font.Bold = False
        Do While .Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceNone)
          .Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
          .Range.Text = x(Int((4 * Rnd) + 1))
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

So this is updated macros, i am using .Range.Style = "sss" but after that all words become green(color of style) and not all spacebars replaced.

```
Sub TestRND_StackOverflow()
    Const d = " "
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim Message, Title, Default, n
    Message = "From which page to start ?"    ' Set prompt.
    Title = "TestRND"    ' Set title.
    Default = "1"    ' Set default.
    ' Display message, title, and default value.
    n = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
    'Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToAbsolute, Count:=n ' RETURN TO DESIRED PAGE
    Randomize
    x = Array("Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5")
    With Selection
        .Find.Text = d
        .Find.MatchCase = True
        .Find.Font.Bold = False
        Do While .Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceNone)
          .InsertBefore " " & x(Int((4 * Rnd) + 1))
          .MoveStartUntil " "
          .Range.Style = "sss"
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
       ActiveDocument.SpellingChecked = True
       MsgBox "Finish", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: With each word you insert you insert 2 new spaces `" Word1 "` before and after that word. So I don't see how this would ever stop running if you don't stop inserting new spaces that then have to be replaced.

Comment: You could workaround that by first replace all spaces by somthing that does not exist in the text. Like replace all spaces by `###` in the whole document first and then in a second step replace `###` by your random words from the array `x`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! This is good idea, with your suggestion my code start working.

Comment: This is a good example indeed, thx macropod

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
Sub TestRND()
    
    Const d = " "
    Dim x As Variant
    Randomize
    Selection.HomeKey wdStory
    x = Array("Word1", "Word2", "Word3", "Word4", "Word5")
    With Selection
        .Find.Text = d
        .Find.MatchCase = True
        .Find.Font.Bold = False
        Do While .Find.Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceNone)
          .InsertBefore " " & x(Int((4 * Rnd) + 1))
          .MoveStartUntil " "
          .Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And if i wish to change style, only of those new random words, how i can apply a specific style to only new words ? Because if i use:

          Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sss")
          .Range.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("sss")
And my sss style applies to whole document...

Comment: In that case, you need to apply a *character* Style before .Collapse wdCollapseEnd, as in .Range.Style = "sss"

Comment: I am using .Range.CharacterStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles("sss") before .Collapse and receiving error, 5173 that name of this style is already exist or reserved for built in styles. And yes, i've created style "sss" before, in order to apply for random words, but why i get this error i dont understand.

Comment: What you're using isn't what I suggested...

Comment: I've made it, now its working. I use Selection.Style = "sss". Thanks for your giude. All the best!

Comment: But for some reason, not all words are with required style. Some words style still old, in random order. Looks like some words are skipped with applie of new style.

Comment: What you're using *still* isn't what I suggested! The Style also won't be changed on any of the random words that appeared in your document before the macro was run...

Comment: where i can read more about character style you've mentioned above ? Cause i read on microsoft docs, there is not much about it

Comment: Paul, help me please, this is important task for me, im stuck

Comment: I still see no indication you have implemented the  .Range.Style = "sss" code I suggested...

Comment: Help, im desperate...

Comment: The code I posted - plus the modifications I suggested at your request - already does all that you asked for. You chose to do something different...